# Error in confusionMatrix(pred, as.factor(owner.df$Probability > 0.5, "owner", : object 'pred' not found in R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am trying to run the code in my book, "Data Mining for Business Analytics Concepts, Techniques, and Applications in R" Chapter, 5.

The code it gives is the following:

```
#### Table 5.5
library(caret)
library(e1071)

owner.df <- read.csv("/Users/Desktop/HOMEWORK/Assignment 3 - Chapter 5 In Chapter Code/ownerExample.csv")

confusionMatrix(as.factor(ifelse(owner.df$Probability>0.5, 'owner', 'nonowner')), 
                owner.df$Class)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(ifelse(owner.df$Probability>0.25, 'owner', 'nonowner')), 
                owner.df$Class)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(ifelse(owner.df$Probability>0.75, 'owner', 'nonowner')), 
                owner.df$Class)
```

head(owner.df)

"Class" is chr
"Probability" is dbl

Error code:

confusionMatrix(as.factor(ifelse(owner.df$Probability>0.5, 'owner', 'nonowner')),

- ```
              owner.df$Class)
  ```

Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This just means that `owner.df$Class` needs to be a factor with the same values as the factor you're creating from `owner.df$Probability`, namely 'owner', 'nonowner'.

Comment: Colin - I did as you suggested, now I get the error: error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

Answer (score 0):

After many years, the default of `read.csv` has changed at R version 4.0 from `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` to `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. R has a categorical data class called factor, which you can create using `factor`, or `as.factor` as in your example.

```
owner.df <- read.csv("ownerExample.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
confusionMatrix(
    as.factor(ifelse(owner.df$Probability>0.5, 'owner', 'nonowner')), 
    owner.df$Class)
```

The `confusionMatrix` function compares instances of a classification. This exercise is showing you that how you cut your predictor, Probability, will change your true and false classification rates. Each position in the two vectors corresponds to an owner. The second vector is the "truth", and the first vector is the guess/prediction.

In the comments you saw an error:

```
confusionMatrix(
    as.factor(ifelse(owner.df$Probability>0.5, '1', '2')), 
    owner.df$Class)
# Error in confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(ifelse(owner.df$Probability of 2 > : 
# The data must contain some levels that overlap the reference.
```

This is because you are comparing the observed value "owner" with the predicted value "1". It would not be appropriate for the program to attempt to second guess the user's intention with this!

Comment: Thank you both. This is very valuable information. *CSJCampbell - this is really good to know. I am using the most current version of R so I can really take advantage of this.

Comment: I also tried the following code that worked for me in another part on as assignment that                                                                                                         
   I actually created the matrix instead of calling a file:  `code` confusionMatrix(as.factor(ifelse(owner.df$`Probability of 2`>0.5, '1', '2')), 
                as.factor(owner.df$Class))
I know get this error: Error in confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(ifelse(owner.df$`Probability of 2` > : The data must contain some levels that overlap the reference.